# How do I recreate this bouncy effect?

Tags: after-effects, animation

I was wondering how this 'bouncy' effect is done when the computer comes up. Is it with keyframes or an expression? Has it a specific name? I have searched for bouncy effect tutorials but couldn't find one that explains this effect.

[bouncy effect video example](https://infinit.io/_/3nvnKuG)

Comment: Related: http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/16045/how-do-i-create-this-slide-bouncy-effect-in-after-effects/

Answer (score 1):

This is called "Inertial Bounce" and has a handy expression to do all the work!

https://gist.github.com/animoplex/aafd6a157282351c8dfeea385d969ef2

```
amp = 5.0; freq = 2.0; decay = 4.0;

n = 0;
if (numKeys > 0) {
  n = nearestKey(time).index;
  if (key(n).time > time) { n--; }
}
if (n == 0) { t = 0; }
else { t = time - key(n).time; }
if (n > 0 && t < 1) {
  v = velocityAtTime(key(n).time - thisComp.frameDuration/10);
  value + v*(amp/100)*Math.sin(freq*t*2*Math.PI)/Math.exp(decay*t);
}
else { value; }
```

Here's a quick video tutorial as well:

Hope this helps you out!